# Regex match line except those with xxx

Tags: regex

Here's my data:

```
public System.Collections.Generic.List<MyItem> MyItemGroupList() {
        return base.Channel.MyItemGroupList();
}

public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyItem> MyItemGroupListAsync(){
        return base.Channel.MyItemGroupListAsync();
}

public OtherItem OtherItemByParam(string param) {
        return base.Channel.OtherItemByParam(param);
}
```

Here's my regex:

```
/(?<=return base\.Channel\.)(.*?)(?=\(.*\);)/g
```

```
MATCH 1
1.  [102-117]   `MyItemGroupList`
MATCH 2
1.  [242-262]   `MyItemGroupListAsync`
MATCH 3
1.  [370-386]   `OtherItemByParam`
```

But I don't want to match any function with Async in the name.
I just can't get it to work.

I've tried inserting `(?!Async)` but just can't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use negative lookahead assertion.

```
(?<=\breturn base\.Channel\.)(?![^()]*Async)\w+
```

`(?![^()]*Async)` asserts that the string going to be matched won't contain the `Async` until `(` is reached.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pA4dN6/1)